# scala how do you group elements in a map

Tags: scala, loops, dictionary

I would like to group elements in a list with the following element if and only if they end with a specific literal string (`chain` in this case). How might I accomplish this?

This is what I have:

```
val rules_intial = List("r1", "r2", "r3 chain", "r4", "r5 chain", "r6 chain", "r7")
```

This is what I want to obtain:

```
val rules_final = List("r1", "r2", List("r3 chain", "r4"), List("r5 chain", "r6 chain",  "r7chain", "r8"), "r9", List("r10chain", "r11"))
```

Comment: It's not clear.

Comment: Please don't put a link to a screenshot of code - copy and paste your code, so we can see it right here, which lets us copy and paste it into our own editor. Also, if the image link ever breaks, no one will have any idea what your code was.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what you're aiming for:

```
List(List(r1), List(r2), List(r3 chain, r4), List(r5 chain, r6 chain, r7))
```

then here is a possibility:

```
val rules = List("r1", "r2", "r3 chain", "r4", "r5 chain", "r6 chain", "r7")

val (groups, last) = rules.foldLeft(List[List[String]](), List[String]()) {
  case ((groups, curGroup), rule) if rule.contains("chain") =>
    (groups, rule :: curGroup)
  case ((groups, Nil), rule) =>
    (List(rule) :: groups, Nil)
  case ((groups, curGroup), rule) =>
    ((rule :: curGroup).reverse :: groups, Nil)
}

val finalGroups = last match {
  case Nil  => groups
  case list => list.reverse :: groups
}

finalGroups.reverse
```